# Start/Stop Java app from web ui

Tags: java, web, interface, restart

I've written a IRC Bot in Java, and I've been looking into a way to start and stop the entire program from PHP.

I've thought about using exec() for starting it, and having a socket listener to make it quit, but I've never used a socket listener before, let alone send data to it from PHP!

(Running on windows server, no screen pls)

Any ideas? (Examples? Links?)

Thanks guys.

EDIT: A friend bounced an idea off me, is there some way that I make the program stop by sending POST or GET data to a Java Program?

Comment: Have you tried looking up anything? ServerSocket examples are widly available. The SO community will help you to debug your code, but will not write it for you. Please post back with any specific issues you are having.

Comment: @MattClark Thanks for the reply, I'm not looking for anyone to write code for me, more along the lines of ideas! I've been brainstorming ideas on this for a couple days, but haven't found anything that seems viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion of various other options...

Keep reading from the socket for the incoming requests...Say on port 9000 and parse the request.

So for instance you receive the request param say : stop_server=true then on reading such param stop the java program by calling a

`System.exit(1);`

Here's something for reference.

1.) Open a socket on a non standard port.

```
server_socket = new ServerSocket(9090, 0, localhost);
```

2.) Now start listening.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            client = server_socket.accept();
                            Log.v("test","accepted");
                            IncomingMessage incomingMessage=new IncomingMessage(client);
                            incomingMessage.processMessage();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Log.v("Exception", "", e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

3.) Now parse your request.

```
streamReader = new InputStreamReader(incomingStream.getInputStream());
reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

while ((str1 = reader.readLine()).startsWith("GET")) {
            if (str1.contains("phone")
                    & str1.contains("LOCATION=false")) {
                String params = str1.substring(5);
                Log.d("substring", params);
                String paramStart = params.substring(1,
                        "phone".length() + 13);
                Log.d("substring-", paramStart);
                smsNumber = paramStart.split("=")[1];

            } else if (str1.contains("LOCATION=true")
                    & str1.contains("phone")) {

                String params = str1.substring(5);
                Log.d("substring", params);
                String paramStart = params.substring(1,
                        "phone".length() + 13);
                smsNumber = paramStart.split("=")[1];

                LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
                criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);

                String provider = manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                CharSequence location_string = String.valueOf(latitude)
                        + "," + String.valueOf(longitude).toString();
                MESSAGE = MAP_LINk + location_string;

            } else if (str1.contains("IMAGE=true")) {

                try {

                    Camera mcamera = Camera.open();
                    mcamera.startPreview(); 
                    mcamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data,
                                Camera camera) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            File mpicture = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                            if (mpicture == null) {
                                Log.d("*************",
                                        "NULL****************");
                                Log.v("test", "image not clicked");
                                writer.write("Picture could not be clicked:");
                                writer.flush();
                            }
                            try {

                                FileOutputStream outputfile = new FileOutputStream(
                                        "sdcard/DCIM/Camera/test.jpg");
                                outputfile.write(data);
                                outputfile.close();
                                MESSAGE = String.valueOf(data);
                                writer.write("Done-------------------");
                                writer.flush();
                                Log.v("test", "image clicked and saved in sdcard");
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                Log.d("EXCEPTION", "MESSAGE", e);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    mcamera.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.v("EXCEPTION", "The picture could not be taken.", e);
                }
            }
            if (!str1.contains("IMAGE=true")) {
                SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                manager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, MESSAGE, null,
                        null);
            }
            writer.write("MESSAGE SENT\nMESSGE-DETAILS\n" + MESSAGE+smsNumber);
            writer.flush();
        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        Log.v("Sockets", "closed");
    }
```

**FYI**

Don't just copy paste it, its actually in context with a project i made in android. So i have tried to skip the platform specific things. Its just to give an idea on how to send a http request to a java program.

**Further reading on sockets**

Getting started

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Some more...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/